# Rails URL generator switch http / https

Tags: ruby-on-rails, urlhelper

Is there a way to put in links to external resources that automatically adds the protocol based on the current protocol?

For example I want to show images from Facebook's Graph API. I was hoping I could do something like:

```
image_tag url_for("/1234567/picture", :host => "graph.facebook.com")
```

So that the `url_for` just bases the protocol on the current request's protocol.

I know this works but I'm hoping there's a better way:

```
image_tag("#{request.protocol}://graph.facebook.com/1234567/picture")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add the protocol option to url_for.

```
image_tag url_for("/1234567/picture", :host => 'graph.facebook.com', :protocol => request.protocol)
```

or maybe a better way would be to create a helper (if you do this a lot) called `url_for_same_protocol` (or whatever you want):

```
class ApplicationHelper
  def url_for_same_protocol(url, options)
    options[:protocol] ||= request.protocol
    url_for url, options
  end
end
```

.. and then just replace your `url_for` call with `url_for_same_protocol`.

Comment: That was what I was hoping for but that doesn't work. url_for accepts either a full url string or a hash of options where you can specify action, controller, host, protocol, etc. but not both